# Widget calls Broadcast only one time

Tags: android, android-widget, android-service, android-broadcast, android-broadcastreceiver

I have an app widget that sends a broadcast, then a broadcast receiver will start a service, the problem is when clicking the widget it would only work at the first time, then I have to open the app to stop the service.

this the widget code:

```
public class Widget extends AppWidgetProvider {
    int appWidgetId;
    RemoteViews views;

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
        for (int i = 0; i < appWidgetIds.length; i++) {
            appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];
            views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);
            Intent bIntent = new Intent(context,BroadCast.class);
            PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, bIntent,0);
            views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widgetbtn, pIntent);
            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
        }
    }
}
```

The broadcast:

```
public class BroadCast extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent serviceIntent=new Intent(context,Service.class);
                if (!isServiceOn) {
                    context.startService(serviceIntent);
                } else {
                    context.stopService(serviceIntent);
                }
            }
    }
```

But it works fine when I send the broadcast from the main activity.

Comment: Does `onReceive()` get called each time? Add logging or use a debugger to check. If so, what is the value of `isServiceOn` ?

Comment: `onReceive()` get called only the first time I add and click the widget, then it does not get called at all. `isServiceOn` value is `false` and it get changed inside the service. @David

Comment: do you see any exceptions in the logcat? Don't filter the logcat or you might miss something important!

Comment: There is nothing.  @David

Comment: Does this happen on devices? Which ones? What Android versions?